# $x$ survives in $G/G^{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am searching for a directly proof of the fact that:
If $G$ is f.g. torsion-free nilpotent group, then every (nontrivial) $x 
\in G$, $x \notin G^{p}$ for all, but finitely many primes $p$

Comment: So a finintely generated, torsion free, nipotent group, it is not possible that for all primes, $x = y^p$ for some $y$.  Hmmm...

Comment: If $G$ is finitely generated torsion-free nilpotent, then so is $G/Z(G)$. So you can use induction on the class of $G$.

Comment: I think of that. But I think we need to distinguish cases on whether $x \in Z(G)$ and $x \notin Z(G)$. In the case that $x \notin Z(G)$ we can use the induction hypothesis, but I can't continue the argument in the case that $x \in Z(G)$.

Comment: It can be shown that, for primes $p$ larger than the class of the group, the set of $p$-th powers forms a subgroup. (I guess I'll need to prove that or find a reference.) If you accept that, then the elements of $Z(G) \cap G^p$ must be $p$-th powers of elements in $Z(G)$ (since $G/Z(G)$ is torsion-free), and the result follows from the abelian case.

Comment: I think that I found a reference("Lectures notes on nilpotent groups", Baumslag). Thank you very much for your time.